# What is the difference between using sqoop & using oraoop in Cloudera Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, rdbms, sqoop

When we have **sqoop** to import data from any RDBMS, then why **oraoop** is raised to import data from **oracle** which is  also a **RDBMS**.

whats is the difference between **sqoop** and **oraoop**

Answer (score 3):

sqoop is generic and works with any RDBMS - the only requirement being that you supply it with the particular RDBMS' JDBC driver.

Oraoop is a special plugin for sqoop that provides faster access to Oracle's RDBMS by using custom protocols that are not available publicly. Quest software partnered with Oracle to get those protocols, implemented them and created Oraoop.

You can also make your sqoop work with Oracle without oraoop but it would not be as fast.

Comment: ,Thank you , so why sqoop is slow in case of oracle and why fast in case of mysql....what could be the reason?

Comment: If the data size is same and if its run under same environment, then its because of the JDBC driver performance.
You can write a simple JDBC program and benchmark the relative performance. In the backend sqoop uses JDBC.

Comment: it's a lot about the impact on the oracle, with oraoop is much more limited and the fact is important because this will help you to save resource on the db

Comment: Quest software has been bought by Dell. And the code of oraoop went into sqoop. 

Now, if you use the oraoop code (by using the --direct clause), sqoop evaluates if the oraoop is faster and will execute via oraoop if so